# Does iOS safari support playing cross domain audio?

Tags: html, ios, cross-domain, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I am trying to play audio after a touch on my website using audio element but the audio file is on aws cloud front. The audio is audible on Desktop Chrome but I cannot hear it on iOS Safari . 
Do they permit it , if yes then is there a config file that we need to create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your titled question: yes mobile Safari does allow to play cross domain HTML5 audio (just tested it again on my iOS7 iPad). Though there has been report it is not working well with [CORS attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906628/cross-origin-video-in-safari).

You could try to wildcard CORS on CloudFront. Maybe this can [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666971/why-is-cloudfront-varying-cors-headers-response-based-on-accept-encoding) you. 
Are you able to plug your iOS device on a Mac to use Safari debug console for iOS? If so there could be error showing up in the logs.

Comment: Thanks, I made it to simple http, even removed SSL. Now everything is fine :-)